# Can binomial distribution be used to sample noise for Ring-LWE-based homomorphic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

Homomorphic encryption schemes based on Ring-LWE need to sample the noise terms from a discrete probability distribution $\chi$ over the integers with support $[-B,B]$. For example, the [Fan-Vercauteren encryption scheme](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/144.pdf) uses the discrete Gaussian distribution.

Several Ring-LWE-based public key encryption and key encapsulation schemes, e.g., [NewHope](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1092.pdf), [Kyber](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf), etc, use binomial distributions instead of discrete Gaussians since they are easier to sample from. Can a similar optimization be made for homomorphic encryption schemes?

Comment: Yes. Though, this is only efficient for small standard deviation.